# Rally 2.0 API - Getting Selected Project Name

Tags: rally

Is there anyway to get the current selected project name in Rally? I'm using SDK 2.0 API with JavaScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var currentProjectName =  Rally.environment.getContext().getProject().Name;
 console.log(currentProjectName);
```

For more info please see [Context](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/context) in the documentation.

Comment: Do You know how to get this variable from Rally's query perspective? (I want to use this in Custom List app)